# How does find evaluate expressions?

Tags: find

`find` man page says that `-print` action has a value of `true`, so why does this command

```
find /home \( -not -print \)
```

always list all files in directory ?

Comment: What output were you expecting from `-print` , if not the filenames?

Comment: He may want to later construct more elaborate expressions, and wants/needs a way to express `false`?

Comment: You would need `-prune` or `-quit` to make `find` stop finding things.

Answer (score 4):

The `-print` action does have a value of true but only *after* it prints.

Observe that this prints all the files twice:

```
$ find .  -print  -print
.
.
./file1
./file1
./file2
./file2
```

Despite having two print statements, this command only prints once:

```
$ find . \( -not -print \) -print
.
./file1
./file2
```

Here, the first `-print` evaluates to true so `-not -print` evaluates to false.  Consequently, the second print is not executed.